# expo-print to download the pdf to my local device on andriod using react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am using expo and expo-print in react-native project to convert html to pdf and then download that pdf in user's download folder I tried

```
const downloadFromUrl = async (activityLogs) => {
  const htmlContent = createHtmlContent(activityLogs);

    const file = await printToFileAsync({
      html: htmlContent,
      base64: true
    });
    console.log(file.uri);
    await shareAsync(file.uri);
};
```

Pdf is downloaded on ios but on andriod it is not being downloaded , it is showing share screen in andriod.